# coredata kvo count

Tags: objective-c, core-data, key-value-observing

Is it possible to set up a KVO trigger for the count of a number of entities in CoreData?

At the moment I'm watching the "DidSaveNotification" but it triggers a lot.

Is there another, better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Can you do your tracking in `-awakeFromInsert` and `-prepareForDeletion`?

Comment: I would use `prepareForDeletion` instead of `validateForDelete` (just my 2 cent :-)

Comment: Oops, yes, `prepareForDeletion` is a better approach.